# Proper way to show admin bar in HTML5 Blank theme

Tags: child-theme

I made a child theme of HTML5 blank where I want to do some modifications like showing the admin bar.

A solution that I found on SO is this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739096/html5-blank-theme-wp-admin-bar

But that is not a good solution because the modification happens in the parent theme's `functions.php` file.

I also noticed that on line 379 of the functions.php in the parent theme if I change `add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'remove_admin_bar');` into  `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true');` 
the change works fine.

Now all I want is to simply create a functions.php file inside my-child-theme/functions.php and simply paste `add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_true');` in it but that doesn't seem to do anything. The child theme works fine and other modifications are also working fine outside the functions.php file. From what I gathered, simply adding functions.php to your child theme should make it able to have the content override the parent's file, no?

Comment: No it's doesn't override first child-theme's `functions.php` is loaded and then parent theme's

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, I found the solution here:
https://pagecrafter.com/how-to-remove-filters-using-child-theme/

The thing is this: 
1) do not touch the function in parent theme, 
2) remove that filter in the child function.php in this way:

```
//Remove the filter that removes the admin bar
function remove_parent_filters(){ //Have to do it after theme setup, because child theme functions are loaded first
    remove_filter('show_admin_bar', 'remove_admin_bar');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_filters' );
```